# JQuery stopped working on all transisions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had my slideshow running fine several months ago, then after not using it for a while i saw the slideshow no longer working. I have also noticed other jquery transisions no longer work. Pretty sure I did not edit any coding etc and am not sure what has caused the error. I am rather inexperienced so not sure if I have missed something basic.

http://www.michaeldank.com/index.html

Comment: Can you post specific codes here?

Comment: All of your `<script>` elements link to local files. See e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///E|/Office/Design/Websites/grayscalecreative.com.au/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>`.

Comment: BTW. Might want to change your question to read something like, how do I solve "Can't find variable: $"

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your JQuery was changed to load from local sources.  These source lines are from your website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///E|/Office/Design/Websites/grayscalecreative.com.au/js/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///E|/Office/Design/Websites/grayscalecreative.com.au/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///E|/Office/Design/Websites/grayscalecreative.com.au/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///E|/Office/Design/Websites/grayscalecreative.com.au/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
```

Probably just fixing those'll solve things.

Comment: Of course, that would make sense! Thanks Saeven.